# How to parallel gitlab-ci script steps

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a job in gitlab-ci that looks like this:

```
job_name:
  script:
    - someExe.exe --auto-exit 120
    - script.py
  needs:
    - some_needs
  stage: stage
  tags:
    - tags
```

someExe.exe is an executable that will run for 120 seconds. I want to start this executable, and while it is running, i want to start script.py. The problem is, gitlab will wait until someExe.exe stops running, and then runs script.py.

Is there any way to do what i want?Preferably, in only one job(having 2 jobs, one that starts .exe and one that starts script.py is not good)

Comment: What kind of runner is it? Linuxy you can do `- (someExe.exe &) && script.py` . I supposed there is something you can do in windows as well to make exe run as background process.

Answer (score 1):

Do your requirements allow for two different jobs with the same stage name? If so, gitlab-ci will run them in parallel:

```
stages:
 - my-stage

some-exe:
  script:
    - someExe.exe --auto-exit 120
  needs:
    - some_needs
  stage: my-stage
  tags:
    - tags

py-script:
  script:
    - script.py
  needs:
    - some_needs
  stage: my-stage
  tags:
    - tags
```